# Теория : Visual Studio + Python

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

Вопрос теоретический. Есть скрипт написанный на Python. Хочу реализовать визуальный интерфейс на C# который будет работать с этим скриптом. Подскажите реально ли это? Где найти информацию по этому поводу? Основные камни преткновения следующие: в visual studio есть, например, IronPython, но в скрипте используются сторонние библиотеки. Как их интегрировать в код написанный в visual studio и это вообще реально ? Я правильно понимаю что вся философия VS и была завязана на том что можно писать код на разных языках разным разработчикам для большего комфорта и получения большего профита. Есть возможность реализовать мою задумку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Философия Visual Studio в том, что бы было комфортно работать с тем или иным языком программирования, интеграция с инструментами и т.д. А связь разных языков, платформ это уже всё от разработчиков оных зависит.

IronPython это по сути Python.NET, а значит сборка созданная в нём будет видна и в C#. Подключаете её и пишите любой интерфейс какой захочется.

Если я не ошибаюсь, то IronPython базируется на python 2+, а значит, если ваш скрипт написан для python 3+, его придётся переписать.

Если скрипт небольшой, то возможно есть смысл переписать его на том же C#.
Или же запускать скрипт на питоне и обмениваться данными с программой на C#.

Comment: `запускать скрипт на питоне и обмениваться данными с программой на C#` сделать тот же вебсервер на питоне и обмениваться сообщениями через json/xml :)

Comment: можно литературу по сабжу?